# Ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado en Advantage Data Architect

Tags: sql

Estoy creando una aplicación con el servidor de base de datos Advantage. Quiero insertar un dato usando el procedimiento almacenado

Intenté con un parámetro de entrada, este es el procedimiento almacenado:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FolioComp
 ( 
 @NumFolio CHAR ( 11 )
 ) 
 BEGIN 

 SELECT COMPRAS.NO_REFEREN, NO_FACT_PR, NUMERO_A, F_FACTURA, ALMACEN, 
 TIPO_MON, CANTIDAD, CLAVE_ART, DESCUENTO, DESCUENTO2, DESCUENTO3, 
 DESCUENTO4, COSTO, IEPS, IMPUESTO, COSTO + IMPUESTO + ISNULL (IEPS, 0) AS 
 TOTAL
 FROM COMPRAS JOIN PARTCOMP ON COMPRAS.NO_REFEREN = PARTCOMP.NO_REFEREN
 WHERE COMPRAS.NO_REFEREN = @NumFolio;
 END;
```

A la hora de ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado:

```
 EXECUTE PROCEDURE SP_FolioComp
 (
 'A0000000012'
 );
```

Me sale este error:

```
 poQuery: Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = HY000;   NativeError = 5154;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] Error 5154:  Execution of the stored procedure failed.  Error 7200:  AQE Error:  State = S0000;   NativeError = 2121;  [iAnywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL Engine]Column not found: @NumFolio -- Location of error in the SQL statement is: 315 (line: 4 column: 28)
```

Comment: No creo que puedes darle nombres a los parámetros con el símbolo `@`. Prueba solo con `NumFolio` tanto en la declaración como en su uso en la consulta.

Comment: Ya lo eh intentado y de igual manera me sigue generando el mismo error.

Comment: ¿Cual versión de Advantage usas?

Comment: La versión es la 9.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De lo que puedo entender de [la documentación de esta base de datos](https://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage9.0/extprocs/stored_procedures.htm), parece que los parámetros de entrada de un procedimiento son accesibles a través de una tabla virtual llamada `__input`. Y cada parámetro vendría siendo una columna de esta tabla virtual.

Si esto es cierto, entonces deberías poder agregar un join a esta tabla virtual para poder acceder al parámetro. Prueba algo así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FolioComp(NumFolio CHAR(11)) 
BEGIN 
    SELECT COMPRAS.NO_REFEREN,
           NO_FACT_PR,
           NUMERO_A,
           F_FACTURA,
           ALMACEN, 
           TIPO_MON,
           CANTIDAD,
           CLAVE_ART,
           DESCUENTO,
           DESCUENTO2,
           DESCUENTO3, 
           DESCUENTO4,
           COSTO,
           IEPS,
           IMPUESTO,
           COSTO + IMPUESTO + ISNULL(IEPS, 0) AS TOTAL
      FROM COMPRAS
      JOIN PARTCOMP
        ON COMPRAS.NO_REFEREN = PARTCOMP.NO_REFEREN
      JOIN __input
        ON __input.NumFolio = COMPRAS.NO_REFEREN;
END;
```

Nota que le quité el símbolo `@` del nombre del parámetro por si acaso. Pero tal vez funcione con él también.

También, por si te ayudara en un futuro, parece que en las versiones más recientes de Advantage, ya no es necesario usar esta tabla virtual `__input`. Mas bien, puedes usar los nombres de parámetros directamente, pero agregando un `_` al frente del nombre. O sea que, tomando el ejemplo arriba, para acceder al parámetro `NumFolio`, pudieras hacerlo usando `_NumFolio` en la consulta. ([Referencia](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage11.1/index.html?master_create_procedure.htm))

Answer (score 1):

Según veo te falta recibir el parámetro meterlo en una variable ponerlo en tu consulta y declarar cada uno de los campos que te va a regresar tu consulta con la palabra OUTPUT y declarar un CURSOR.

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE SP_FolioComp
    (
       NumFolio CHAR ( 11 ),
       NOREFERENV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT,
       NOFACTPRV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT,
       NUMEROAV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT,
       FFACTURAV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT,
       ALMACENV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT,
       TIPOMONV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT,
       COSTOV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT,
       IEPSV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT,
       IMPUESTOV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT,
       TOTALV ["TipoDato"] ( ? ) OUTPUT
    ) 

    BEGIN 
    DECLARE Fol CHAR (11);
    DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR;
    Fol = (SELECT NumFolio FROM __input);

    OPEN cursor1 AS

    SELECT NO_REFEREN AS NOREFERENV, 
           NO_FACT_PR AS NOFACTPRV,
           NUMERO_A AS NUMEROAV,
           F_FACTURA AS FFACTURAV,
           F_EMISION AS FEMISIONV, 
           ALMACEN AS ALMACENV,
           TIPO_MON AS TIPOMONV,
           COSTO AS COSTOV,
           IEPS AS IEPSV,
           IMPUESTO AS  IMPUESTOV,
           COSTO + IMPUESTO + ISNULL (IEPS, 0) AS TOTALV
           FROM COMPRAS 
           WHERE NO_REFEREN LIKE Fol;

    WHILE FETCH cursor1 DO
    INSERT INTO __output VALUES (
        cursor1.NOREFERENV,
        cursor1.NOFACTPRV,
        cursor1.NUMEROAV,
        cursor1.FFACTURAV,
        cursor1.FEMISIONV,
        cursor1.ALMACENV,
        cursor1.TIPOMONV,
        cursor1.COSTOV,
        cursor1.IEPSV,
        cursor1.IMPUESTOV,
        cursor1.TOTALV
        );
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE cursor1;

    END;
```

Procura poner el mismo nombre del alias a los parámetros de salida.